# How to use Embedding with C#? Discord BOT

Tags: c#, embed, discord, discord.net

I am looking to embed the following:
[image: Embed Pic]

Using the Discord API. I have looked and the only resources I can find are for Python, Java, Ruby, etc.

But when using:

```
var embed = new Message.Embed(
{
    Author =
    {
        Name = "Name",
        Url = "www.url.com"
    }
});
```

It comes back with the message:

[image: Error on MEssage.Embed]

And:

[image: Error on Name and URL]

Not sure What I need to do to be able use the embed library. Just looking for some guidance on how this works

Edit:

When Using this I get no errors but when running the embed doesnt seem to build. It doesnt error. It just never builds the embed variable

```
var embed = new Message.Embed
            {
                Author =
                {
                Name = "Lawler",
                Url = "www.twitch.tv/Lawler"
                },
                Title = "www.twitch.tv/Lawler",
                Thumbnail =
                {
                ProxyUrl = "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-m-P7t2g-ecQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/YtS2YsD8-AM/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg",
                Url = "www.twitch.tv/Lawler"
                },
                Description = "**Now Playing**\n" +
                              "Rocket League\n" +
                              "**Stream Title**\n" +
                              "Lawler RLCS Caster"

            };
```

*Note: I am using Discord v 0.9.6

Comment: Can u share sample project?

Comment: @BorisIvanov Here is the link to the Sample I found for Java.

[LINK](https://yorkaargh.gitbooks.io/discord-js-bot-guide/content/samples/using-embeds-in-messages.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an Embed Message like the following code (using the most recent version of Discord.Net):

```
var builder = new EmbedBuilder()
{
    //Optional color
    Color = Color.Green,
    Description = "This is the description of the embed message"
};
```

Build a field inside the Embed Message:

```
builder.AddField(x =>
{
    x.Name = Author.Name;
    x.Value = Author.Url;
    x.IsInline = false;
});
```

And reply to the same channel context:

```
//Use await if you're using an async Task to be completed.
await ReplyAsync("", false, builder.Build())
```

The code above should build an embed message, there are more options in the Discord.Net docs. Link: https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/introduction/intro.html

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick look at your code, I think you've got a close parenthesis in the wrong place.

Try the following:

```
var embed = new Message.Embed()
{
    Author =
    {
        Name = "Name",
        Url = "www.url.com"
    }
};
```

Again, without doing any research you may also need to do the following:

```
var embed = new Message.Embed()
{
    Author = new Author()
    {
        Name = "Name",
        Url = "www.url.com"
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! See my edit. I now have that working, but anything after the `var embed = new message.embed` doesn't run. It doesnt seem to build the embed

Answer (score 1):

```
    var embed = new EmbedBuilder()
```

instead of

```
var embed = new Message.Embed()
```

To send the message:

```
   await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, embed);
```

**EDIT:** 0.9.6 doesn't support embeds, so the code above is useless

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Discord.Net 1.0.1, you can format an embed like so:

```
var eb = new EmbedBuilder() { Title = "Cool Title", Description = "Description" };
```

Read the documentation here for more info [here](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.EmbedFieldBuilder.html).

And if you want to make your text look a little better, you can read the Discord Markdown Documentation [here](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/210298617-Markdown-Text-101-Chat-Formatting-Bold-Italic-Underline-).  This works in 0.9.6.

To send an embed use:

```
await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, eb);
```

Comment: I know that this is similar to what was said above, but i felt like adding some clarification might help :)